# Gallieo And Android Plugin Error

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I am using Eclipse Gallieo and trying to use the Android Plugin.But i am getting the following errors.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Android Development Tools
>   16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)   Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534
>   (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have at least Eclipse Helios installed to proceed with the ADT installation.

Comment: I downloaded the Indigo version and then checked and unchecked the updates and then later added the adt plugin URL and now its fine and working. Thanks for the response.

Comment: I have Eclipse Helios but I can't install the ADT, some dependency problem comes up.

Comment: I suggest you to check/uncheck the updates for Helios and delete ur ADT plugin URL and then first check for Software updates, once it done. Then Add the url for ADT plugin. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

I had indigo installed and received this error so it is clearly not the version that matters. My install of the ADT fails giving me this error as well.

Uninstall and re-install the latest version from the website. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Windows Vista and I had the same error message. What I did to solve it was to run the application as administrator (right click in the icon/shortcut and then click on "Run as Administrator").

I read the solution from a linux user who solve the problem runnin

Answer (score 0):

when you are asked to enter the sites address select the option "all the available sites" and the select android packages you want to install thee should be 4 packages.. select these packages .. and proceed ,..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday...and I wasted the whole day..I tried to find the solution, but I couldn't

At last today, I downloaded eclipse again and re-installed it....and now the error has gone...

If you are starting new one..then before that delete the previous one...by removing Workspace folder from your C drive...and then start it...

If you have downloaded recently or have latest version, then try to start it again..after removing the workspace folder and all connected folders....even then, if you don't find solution...Disable your Firewall and Antivirus...and try, you will find the solution....

You can also see this video on youtube "How to install Eclipse / android adt plugin ubuntu/kubuntu 11.10"...Or visit this link for this video "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HCNC34BflOo"...that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

For me (Ubuntu 11.10, Eclipse 3.7) it helped to start eclipse with sudo.

I choose the same workspace as normal but that shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

On `windows 7` right-click and click on `troubleshoot compatibility` and run in the windows xp mode as suggested and it should work.